# DateTime format in the template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, mustache, handlebars.js

I am using mustache templates in my application. The datetime values in JSON are shown below:
How do I convert them in a proper format?

```
Created 
"/Date(1335232596000)/"

Submitted
"/Date(1335214659000)/"
```

Comment: Are you using a JSON serializer or deserializer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to isolate the number with `subString()` and use that as the milliseconds input of a new date.

```
var a = "/Date(1335214659000)/";
var b = parseInt(a.substring(a.indexOf('(')+1,a.indexOf(')')));
var x = new Date(b);
alert(x);
```

Even better make it a function.

```
function GetDateFromJSONData (a) {
  var b = parseInt(a.substring(a.indexOf('(')+1,a.indexOf(')')));
  return new Date(b);
}
var x = GetDateFromJSONData("/Date(1335214659000)/");
```

Comment: Where exactly should I be doing this conversion? Before the data is returned as JSON from the controller?

Comment: I can't tell you that :) I don't know where you need to use it. This answers the question at hand, if you want to know more you'd need to mark this answer and then open a new question. We're typically pretty fast and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Found the following solution at 
http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/13/jquery-templates-in-asp-net-introduction.aspx

. Hope it helps others

```
<html xmlns="www.w3.org/.../xhtml">

<head runat="server">

   <title>...</title>

   <script src="ajax.aspnetcdn.com/.../jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="ajax.aspnetcdn.com/.../jquery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function () {

           var test =

               {

                   Id: '43000796568231937',

                   created_at: '1294003506853-0700'

               };          

           $("#myTemplate").tmpl(test).appendTo("#tblMyTable");

       });

       function FormatDate(jDate) {

           alert("jDate:" + jDate);

           var date = eval(jDate.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));

           alert(date);

           var dDate = new Date(date);

           alert(dDate);

           var year = dDate.getFullYear();

           alert(year);

           return dDate;

       }

   </script>

   <script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">

       <tr><td>${Id} - ${FormatDate(created_at)}</td></tr>

   </script>

</head>

<body>

   <form id="form1" runat="server">

       <table id="tblMyTable"></table>

   </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but the solution for handlebars in 2014 would be to use a helper. For example:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("formatDate", function (datetime) {
    var d = parseInt(datetime.match(/\d+/));
    return new Date(d);
});
```

Then use it in your handlebars template:

```
{{formatDate Created}}
```

or

```
{{formatDate Submitted}}
```

Hope this helps